# PostFix & Exchange

Tags: postfix, exchange-2010

Is it possible for Postfix and Exchange to synchronise thier databases while sharing the same SMTP domain so that if a massage is deleted on Exchange it reflex on Postfix and the other way round?

Comment: Postfix is just an MTA, what databases do you want to synchronise?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: Exchange has a message database called "information store". Some, but not all elements of the information store can be replicated to other Exchange servers via internal replication mechanisms. Those mechanisms are proprietary to Exchange - no other product interops with them.

Postfix on the other hand is an open-source [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) which just forwards mail - it has no database to store it. The message store could be implemented by an IMAP server like Courier or Cyrus, but neither of them would interface with Exchange in the way you asked for.